# calling perl programs from tkinter/ python

Tags: python, perl, tkinter

I'm thinking of learning Python for building GUIs starting with tkinter.  I have some existing libraries in perl that I'd like to call from a Python / tkinter GUI, in order to start relatively quickly, rather than working out how to port those libraries.

Before I start, is this a viable project?  Can I easily call perl functions and programs from a tkinter interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to execute perl scripts u can easily do that via subprocess.popen oder os.cmd. 
If you actually want to import perl scripts and use their functions you could take look at pyperl http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPerl. I think it's unmaintained but I don't know if there's a more recent alternative out.